# A better way to store current user profile

Tags: angularjs

I need to show the name of current user in the top bar of my website. The user data should be disappeared when user logout. I used the following two services:

```
app.factory('Auth', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/user/login');
    }])
    .service('CurrentUser', [function () {
        this.user= null;
    }]);
```

Here is my login and topbar controllers.

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', ['CurrentUser', 'Auth', '$location', function (CurrentUser, Auth, $location) {
        this.login = function () {
            var me = this;
            me.user = Auth.save(me).$promise.then(
                function (res) {
                    CurrentUser.user = res;
                    $location.path("/");
                }, function (res) {
                    me.errors = res.data;
                });
        }
    }])
.controller('TopBarCtrl', ['CurrentUser', function (CurrentUser) {
        var me = this;
        me.user = CurrentUser;
    }])
```

Using this controllers and services in had to use {{contoller.user.user.name}} to show the user's name. Is there any way to use {{contoller.user.name}} instead and keep the two-way bindings?

Comment: is there a particular reason you are not using $scope.currentUser = {user:res}. It only makes sense to store it in service if you are going to access it all over you app. Even through service you can bind

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use

```
me.user = CurrentUser.user;
```

As your are setting the result of your http.save in the first then to the .user property of CurrentUser.

What does the server result, e.g json, look like?

Comment: You need to use reference to two-way binding work. Server response in json format.